# Why can we make those approximations regarding the Big Bang Nucleosynthesis (BBN)?

Tags: cosmology, nucleosynthesis

(About neutron decoupling) Consider
$$p+e^{-}\rightarrow n+\nu_{e}.$$
In particular if we consider temperatures about $\simeq1\mbox{MeV}$ both neutrons and protons are non relativistic and we can find the neutron to proton ratio as
$$\frac{n_{n}}{n_{p}}=\frac{g_{n}}{g_{p}}\left(\frac{m_{n}}{m_{p}}\right)^{3/2}\exp\left(\frac{\mu_{e}-\mu_{\nu}}{T}\right)\exp\left[-\frac{Δ m}{T}\right]$$
Then one usually neglects the exponential with the chemical potentials since
$$\frac{\mu_{e}}{T}\simeq\frac{n_{e}}{n_{\gamma}} \simeq \frac{n_{p}}{n_{\gamma}}=\eta_{B}\ll1$$
My first question is about the last equation: Why can we say that? In particular where does the first passage come from?

(About nuclei formation) To study the deuteron formation
$$p+n\rightarrow d$$
one usually consider the Saha equation
$$\frac{n_{d}}{n_{p}n_{n}}\simeq\frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{4\pi}{m_{p}T}\right)^{3/2}\exp\left(\frac{B_{d}}{T}\right)$$
where we used $g_{p}=g_{n}=2,g_{d}=3$ and $m_{d}\simeq2m_{p}$. At this point one usually say that, if $T_{nuc}$ is such that $n_{d}\simeq n_{p}$, it reduces to (neglecting numerical factors)
$$1\simeq\eta_{B}n_{\gamma}\left(\frac{1}{m_{p}T_{nuc}}\right)^{3/2}\exp\left[\frac{B_{d}}{T_{nuc}}\right]\simeq\eta_{B}\left(\frac{T_{nuc}}{m_{p}}\right)^{3/2}\exp\left(\frac{B_{d}}{T_{nuc}}\right)$$
Well I don't understand why we can approximate the baryon density with the neutron density, can someone help me?